# How to integrate Facebook in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have integrated fbgraph api in the application and can post and update the status on facebook, however didn't know how to update status in certain time interval when the app is in background, In my application user will have options like 3 hrs,5 hrs, 6 hrs to update the status automatically, user can select the any time and when app is in background it updates automatically, i am not getting access token in background, please help

Comment: The access_token is valid for max of 2 hrs. So in your case you are trying to update it after 3 hrs. Which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution!

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: thanks for the url i have previously done that,however in background the status is not updating in certain time interval